Jupyter notebooks hanging midrun when declaringg val name in caps
I m running jupyter notebook on an EC2 instance and connecting to an interactive endpoint mapped to a virtual cluster on EMR on EKS. I am running Spark workflows in jupyter notebooks in scala which uses Apache Toree kernel deployed on the enterpise gateway.
I am seeing a strange behaviour when m cell keep on running indefinitely when i declare a value with name in all caps
val PREFIX = "XYZ_" // cell containing this runs indefinitely

The driver pod does display an error message of chunk tag found
However the following works without any issues:
val prefix = "XYZ_" // works fine

and
def PREFIX = "XYZ_" // this also works fine

I am just wondering if someone can help me understand why the notebook cell run indefinitely when I am declaring value name in caps as highlighted above.
PS: If I run the same code packaged as a ajar through SparkOperator, everything works fine!!
